# How can I stop API returning URL escape code of the characters from URL I am sending through Python code?

Tags: python-3.x, api, escaping, urllib, urlencode

I am trying to query GitLab's API to fetch users.

URL I have passed to the API:
`https://gitlab.com/api/scim/v2/groups/cimpress-technology/Users/waad|5cmnhgd@NVJ4bHFYnhfv_mvbj4KGjguJGka_:`

The response I get back:
`ERROR: Http Error: 401 Client Error: Unauthorized for url:https://gitlab.com/api/scim/v2/groups/XXXXXXX/Users/waad%7C5cmnhgd@NVJ4bHFYnhfv_mvbj4KGjguJGka_:_-c9ef6jS API response we have received: «Response [401]>`

I have noticed the `|` character gets replaced with its URL escape code '%7C' ([Refer URL escape code of |](https://docs.microfocus.com/OMi/10.62/Content/OMi/ExtGuide/ExtApps/URL_encoding.htm))

I have tried multiple ways of URL parsing/encoding like.

```
import urllib.parse
safe_string = urllib.parse.quote_plus(...)
```

I am expecting that it should read the '|' character as it is and not use the `7%C` url escape code instead.

Is there a way I can avoid this?

Thank you

Comment: It shouldn't matter if the character is escaped or not. (Though some characters must be escaped.) I doubt this has anything to do with your error.

Comment: So is it the vendor causing a problem through their API?  How could this be resolved, kind of stuck here

Comment: It looks like the problem is authentication, not your url encoding.

Comment: I am using the same authentication for a bunch of users, but only a handful fail with this error :(